# Why jquery onclick does call action twice

Tags: jquery

I try to add onclick action over element. But its action was called twice. Where is the problem?
I will just give a simple example:

```js
$('#categories').on('click', '.category', function () {
 console.log('why is called twice???');
});
```

```html
<form name="categories" id="categories">
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>All</label>
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>some</label>
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>other</label>
</form>


<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
     integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you click the `label` of a radio button (or checkbox), the `click` event is fired on the `label` (of course), and **also** fired on the radio button. Since `click` bubbles, your handler sees the click both from `label` and from the radio button.

You can see that by logging the `e.target.tagName`:

```js
$('#categories').on('click', '.category', function (e) {
 console.log('Click on: ' + e.target.tagName);
});
```

```html
<form name="categories" id="categories">
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>All</label>
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>some</label>
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>other</label>
</form>


<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
     integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As you can see, if you click the label, you see

```
Click on: LABEL
Click on: INPUT
```

But if you just click the radio button itself (the circle), you only see

```
Click on: INPUT
```

So you may want to only watch for clicks on the radio button, since you'll get those even if it's just the label that was clicked:

```
$('#categories').on('click', '.category > input', function (e) {
  console.log('Click on: ' + e.target.tagName);
});
```

```js
$('#categories').on('click', '.category > input', function (e) {
  console.log('Click on: ' + e.target.tagName);
});
```

```html
<form name="categories" id="categories">
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>All</label>
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>some</label>
 <label class="checkbox category"><input type="radio" name="categories" checked="checked" /><i></i>other</label>
</form>


<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
     integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use it like this:

```
$('#categories').on('click', 'input[name="categories"]', function () {
    console.log('why is called twice???');
});
```

You was calling the click on `label`, and label triggers the focus on input too.